# Weird graphics and boxes when embedding the WebViewBrowser example into my play application

Tags: webview, java-8, playframework-2.2, javafx-8

I created a new application with the play framework and embedded the sample WebViewBrowser example of the JavaFX package starting as a separate thread in a startup method in my play app.

When I run the server and the WebViewer pops up I got boxes around the elements and some of the content is disappearing. I use JDK8 (with the current JavaFX) with PlayFramework 2.2. I read about some kind of debug mode on uncle ggl but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is WebView content fading out (disappearing)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388512/why-is-webview-content-fading-out-disappearing)

Comment: That solution does not work with JDK8 and/or with play framework.